# Is it possible to customize workflow panel?

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions, workflow

I am using Workflow Task process to create activity.
My implementation is following.

1. Editor creates component and page, then create "Review" activity by
   Task process and assign it to reviewer.At that time, write page URL
   to review in "Subject" field of "New Task" panel.
2. Reviewer recieves the activity, and copy URL from "Task Name" on
   workflow activity panel and paste it to browser address bar.

But I think it's better that the URL in "Task Name" is hyperlink and reviewer can go to the URL just click it, not copy and paste the URL.
Is it possible by GUI extension or something like that?

And I have a problem. On Internet Explorer and Chrome, URL in "Task Name" is not fully displayed (only first part is displayed because it's too long), so user cannot copy the URL (Firefox is not a problem). Can this behavior be revised by GUI extension?

Regards,

Comment: Is the URL pointing to your staging website with XPM installed? Because in that case I believe you can cut out the entire manual process by 1) adding the item to the task and 2) having the reviewer open the items from the Task panel within XPM.

Comment: I think you _might_ be able to adjust styles to get that URL to fully display, but for browser differences, consider logging a ticket with Support.

Comment: @Hirozaku - did you write an extension for this? Is this something you could share with the community?